# 3G/4G data plan cost outside your own country

Tags: budget, data-plans, mobile-operators

Talking about YOUR country, and YOUR mobile-operator, how much are your charged (min / med / max) if you use 3G/4G data connection when travelling outside your country ?

Comment: This would appear to be collecting a long list, and not have one correct answer, so doesn't look a good fit for the site

Comment: @Gagravarr : I will synthesize the answers so this question and its answers can help further readers.

Comment: Hi Oliver, as pointed out by Gagravarr this question isn't exactly a good fit for the website as it doesn't have any one correct answer and is a poll. You're welcome to edit the question to make it more specific, if possible.

Answer (score 2):

I'm charged 8 Swiss Francs (~10 USD) per Megabyte.

Answer (score 1):

I answer myself for further readers :

**From :** France
**Destination :** Inside Europe
**My Mobile-operator** : Orange
**Charge :** 5 euros for 10 Mo/day